# How to avoid NotImplementedError "Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use" in django on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I'm using Django 1.1 on Google App Engine through `use_library`. No Django GAE helper, Django non-rel or similar tools are used here. Django handles URLs routing, forms validation etc., but I'm using pure App Engine models.

In one of my Django forms there is a FileField, which from time to time, seems to call **django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile**. This class then uses **tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile** and this results in App Engine raising:

```
File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/tempfile.py", line 45, in PlaceHolder
   raise NotImplementedError("Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use")
```

Trying to solve this problem I took [uploadedfile module](https://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/attachmentText?id=153&aid=2771174282711124630&name=uploadedfile.py&token=8a479bae5a7454ccfbe6f5a9a1d9d5fd) from Google App Engine Helper for Django (which doesn't use `NamedTemporaryFile`) saved it as `gae_uploadedfile.py` in application directory and in my `_djangomain.py_` file I added:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.1')
(...)
import gae_uploadedfile
django.core.files.uploadedfile = gae_uploadedfile
```

*djangomain.py* is a file where i redirect all urls - in *app.yaml* I have:

```
- url: /.*
  script: djangomain.py
```

But it didn't help, I still get this exception. What am I doing wrong, is there other solution to avoid this error while using FileField from `django.forms`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to update the settings.py file with the following to change the default Django behaviour:

```
# only use the memory file uploader, do not use the file system - not able to do so on
# google app engine
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ('django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',)
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440 # the django default: 2.5MB
```

More info here:[FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE) and 
[upload-handlers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#upload-handlers)

If you are uploading images you will be restricted by the 1MB quotas for image transformation etc.. [Quotas_and_Limits](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits)