# NotImplementedError: Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-ads-api

I'm using django and Google App Engine. I can't determine where's the error came from because if I'm using it on local my site is functioning. After I deployed it on GAE it works fine but when using googleadwords api this error comes:

```
NotImplementedError: Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use
at PlaceHolder (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py:45)
at __init__ (/base/data/home/apps/f~xxxx/20180320t181216.408435502723573470/lib/suds/cache.py:115)
at __init__ (/base/data/home/apps/f~xxxx/20180320t181216.408435502723573470/lib/suds/client.py:112)
at GetService (/base/data/home/apps/f~xxxx/20180320t181216.408435502723573470/lib/googleads/adwords.py:459)
at post (/base/data/home/apps/f~xxxx/20180320t181216.408435502723573470/ksvt/views.py:47)
at dispatch (/base/data/home/apps/f~xxxx/20180320t181216.408435502723573470/lib/django/views/generic/base.py:88)
at view (/base/data/home/apps/f~xxxx/20180320t181216.408435502723573470/lib/django/views/generic/base.py:68)
at _get_response (/base/data/home/apps/f~xxxx/20180320t181216.408435502723573470/lib/django/core/handlers/base.py:185)
at _get_response (/base/data/home/apps/f~xxxx/20180320t181216.408435502723573470/lib/django/core/handlers/base.py:187)
at inner (/base/data/home/apps/f~xxxx/20180320t181216.408435502723573470/lib/django/core/handlers/exception.py:41)
```

Can someone explain what is the meaning of this error? Thanks!

Edit:
The line of code that I think generates the error.

```
 adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "//googleads.yaml")
```

Comment: very similar, although old https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586134/how-to-avoid-notimplementederror-only-tempfile-temporaryfile-is-available-for-u

Comment: @EduardGamonal hello sir, I already tried that and it doesn't work. I also updated my question and added the line of code that I think causing the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The adwords library is using `suds` to send SOAP messages to the adwords API.  The suds package tries to cache data in the filesystem, which is forbidden in the App Engine standard environment.

The Adwords package's [README](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib) describes how to disable caching by passing the a dummy cache implementation to the adwords client:

```
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(
  developer_token, oauth2_client, user_agent,
  client_customer_id=client_customer_id, cache=suds.cache.NoCache())
```

(You will need to import `suds.cache`)

Comment: Your the man! I didn't know that cache is forbidden in GAE.. Thank you so much.. my site is working now in GAE.. :)